# Characteristic subgroups of non-abelian $p$-group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, p-groups, characteristic-subgroups

It is a difficult problem to determine **all** the characteristic subgroups of a non-abelian $p$-group. But, then, I would seek for *as many characteristic subgroups* as we can, for small order $p$-groups.

For a non-abelian $p$-group, the most natural list will start from

> $Z(G)$, $[G,G]$, $\mho_n(G)=\langle g^{p^n}\colon g\in G\rangle$, $\Omega_n(G)=\langle g\colon g^{p^n}=1\rangle.$

I would call these type of characteristic subgroups as *primary characteristic subgroups*, since the next characteristic subgroups are obtained from these one. The following are some other characteristic subgroups obtained from *primary* ones:

- One may form $HK$, $H\cap K$, $[H,K]$ where $H,K$ are characteristic.
- For $H$ a characteristic subgroup, take $G/H$ and pull back its characteristic subgroup in $G$.

**Question:** Are there some other *primary characteristic subgroups* for a non-abelian $p$-group?

---

**Note:** In $p$-groups, Frattini is product of two *primary characteristic subgroups*: $[G,G]$ and $\mho_1(G)$.

Comment: You can consider the subgroup generated by all elements x such that there exist elements y and z such that xyxyzyxyxzyzy=1. That subgroup is in fact fully characteristic.

Comment: Also, the subgroup generated by all elements of the form xyzyxzxzxyxyxyzyxyx for some x, y and z.

Comment: The following paper might be useful @article {MR3198722,
    AUTHOR = {Wilson, James B.},
     TITLE = {More characteristic subgroups, {L}ie rings, and isomorphism
              tests for {$p$}-groups},
   JOURNAL = {J. Group Theory},
  FJOURNAL = {Journal of Group Theory},
    VOLUME = {16},
      YEAR = {2013},
    NUMBER = {6},
     PAGES = {875--897},
      ISSN = {1433-5883},
   MRCLASS = {20D15 (20D30 20D45 20F40)},
  MRNUMBER = {3198722},
MRREVIEWER = {Andrea Caranti},
       DOI = {10.1515/jgt-2013-0026},
       URL = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1515/jgt-2013-0026},
}